# Werkzeug crashes with "No module named run" when debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

I have a flask app that runs well until I try debugging it, then it always crashes with `No module named run`

I narrowed it down to `exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)` in [werkzeug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/src/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L266)

What could be the issue here?

Comment: It used to work, but stopped working today for some reason. I have no idea what could have caused it. Already tried cloning it into a different folder, but it yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the directory containing "run" was not in the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Adding it at the top of "run.py" solved the issue:

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += f":{os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))}"
```